# Forced Vibrations

Tags: forces, waves, frequency, oscillators, resonance

Forced Vibrations are the vibrations under the influence of an external periodic force.

Their amplitude depends on the frequency of the external force. If it is equal to the natural frequency of the vibrating body then the amplitude is very large but when it is not equal then the amplitude is very small.

I am unable to understand this established relation between frequency and amplitude and why does this thing(which I stated above) happens.

P.S. : I am a tenth grader so please avoid the use of complicated terminologies.

Comment: try understanding    http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/sound/reson.html  , http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscdr.html

Comment: This can really only be understood in *mathematical terms*.

Comment: @Gert I have a little doubt(different from this question) can you clarify it please?

Comment: If an object has a natural (resonance) frequency and you impose *another* frequency on it then eventually the object ends up 'following' the forced frequency. The transition from natural to forced frequency is mathematically complicated but not really important. If say your hand held drill runs at say 2000 rpm then soon enough the whole drill will vibrate at that frequency.

Comment: @Gert why is it said that when the pitcher gets filled with water its sound becomes shriller but on the contrary I feel it is opposite

Comment: It gets flatter and flatter?

Comment: That has nothing to do with forced vibrations. Filling the glass changes its natural frequency.

Comment: But why do we say it gets shriller and shriller @Gert

Comment: Don't really know, to be honest.

Comment: When filling a pitcher a wide spectrum of sound frequencies are produced.  The ones whose frequencies match the natural frequency of the pitcher resonate and sound louder.  As the pitcher fills, and the air column in it shortens, its natural frequency increases.